# Android emulator displays different colors depending on the grpahics mode (Hardware or Software)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm messing around with the android emulator configurations and I've noticed that using **Hardware GLES 2.0** graphics mode produces different colors than using **Software GLES 2.0**.

The colors produced in the Software mode seems right, while the colors produced in the Hardware mode seems a bit wrong.

[image]

Example:

- Software
  [image]
- Hardware
  [image]

Is there any way to fix the colors while using the **Hardware GLES 2.0** mode?

---

Additional info:

- I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- I'm using the NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-530 (proprietary)